# SSO per tenant in wso2 Identity Server

Tags: identity, saml, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

We want apps login against Identity Server with SAML. Apps will be separated in two domains. Apps in one domain share the sso, but not apps in the other. Example:

- domainOne.com

  - app1
  - app2
- domainTwo.com

  - app3
  - app4

When app1 login against IS, app2 is automatically loged via IS too. But app3 and app4 ask for the user/password against the same IS.

We try it with tenants in IS, but It seems app3 and app4 is loged in too when app1 login.

Are there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that WSO2IS SSO session cookie (`commonauthid`) is NOT based on tenant domain. it is only unique for the server. It must be the reason for above behivor. Someone can see this as a bug. Someone would not. Because,  It is SP's decision to allow the users from other tenant to login not.  Users already authenticated with WSO2IS server and SP must decide whether allow to login or not.

However,  this behavior can be seen when you configure your SP as SAAS applications in the WSO2IS. If you are not configured as SAAS applications, you can not login for different tenant. Because user's tenant domain and  SP's tenant domain would be different. Therefore user must not be able to login. You must see error `Service Provider tenant domian must be equal to user tenant domain for non-SaaS applications"`.  If you have not configured as SAAS app and still user can login for different tenants,  It is probably a bug in the WSO2IS.

However, following is some sample way to do this correctly within SP side.

Say,  there are two app domains FOO and BAR

foo.com tenant contains the SPs from FOO.
bar.com tenant contains the SPs from BAR.

foo.com tenant contains users who can access SPs from FOO.
bar.com tenant contains users who can access SPs from BAR.

Say,  user "bob"  from foo.com access FOO  app  and bob can login with
SSO.   Then SSO cookie would be set in to the "bob" browsers.  SAML
Assertion received from WSO2IS contains the username as  "bob@foo.com". FOO apps can accept the request as user is from foo.com domain.

Also, if  bob tries to access  BAR app using same browser...   login
page will NOT be shown as SSO cookie is there,  WSO2IS identifies the
authenticated user as  "bob@foo.com" Then SAML2 response would be sent to BAR and username inside SAML Assertion would be  "bob@foo.com" Then  BAR app can reject this user as this user is from "foo.com"  So user can not login to  BAR apps.

Therefore SPs have the control of allowing users to login.

Comment: I think It's better you can configure this behaviour in WSO2 IS, not in the SPs. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be some kind of bug in WSO2IS, Please check this https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3301